# Prove for Pedal & Isosceles triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, tangent-line

The tangents at two points $B$ and $C$ on a circle meet at $A$. Let $A_1B_1C_1$ be the pedal triangle of the isosceles triangle $ABC$ for an arbitrary point $P$ on the circle, as shown below. Then prove that $${PA_1}^2 = PB_1 \times PC_1$$
[image]

Comment: This is also true: If a circle passing through $P$ and $C$ meets $BC$ at $A_2$ and the line $AC$ at $B_2$, and the circumcircle of $PA_2B$ meets the line $AB$ at $C_2$,  then $$PA_2^2=PB_2\cdot PC_2\,.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  The triangles $PC_1A_1$ and $PA_1B_1$ are similar (both are similar to the triangle $PBC$).

Comment: please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

**Another hint:** Note that $PA_1BC_1$ has 2 opposite $90^\circ$ angles. Hence it is cyclic. This can help get some angles to prove that $PC_1A_1$ is similar to $PBC$.

Answer (score 1):

$P C_1 B A_1$ is a cyclic quadrilateral since the angles at $A_1$ and $C_1$ are right angles, so $\widehat{PC_1 A_1}=\widehat{P B_1 A_1}$. Moreover,
$$ \widehat{C_1 P A_1} = \pi-\widehat{C_1 B A_1} = \widehat{CBA} = \widehat{BPC} $$
so $PC_1A_1$ and $PBC$ are similar triangles. In the same way, $PA_1 B_1$ and $PBC$ are similar triangles.

You may also apply a circular inversion centered at $P$ and see what happens.